# Cant access Checkbox from another form

Tags: c#

Any help is appreciated

Basically I am having trouble accessing a checkedlistbox on a tab.
I have a checkedlistbox on tab 1 of form 1. I want to pass this checkbox to form 2 and place the results in a listbox on form 2

Form1

```
public static void ShowResults(string strRoutine, string strCaption)
{
    ResultsForm.Routine = strRoutine;
    ResultsForm.Title = strCaption;

    strXMLFileName = xmlDocConfig.SelectSingleNode("config/routine[@key='" + strRoutine + "']/outputfname").Attributes.GetNamedItem("value").Value;

    strXMLFileName = clsUtilities.ReplacePathWildcards(strXMLFileName);

    strXMLFileName = clsUtilities.ReplacePathWildcards(frmNSTDBQC.xmlDocConfig.SelectSingleNode("config/routine[@key='G']/outputfname").Attributes.GetNamedItem("value").Value) + "\\" + strXMLFileName;

    ResultsForm.DisplayFile = strXMLFileName;
    ResultsForm.ShowDialog();
}
```

In form 2 I can access the tab control, I can access `QCForms.tcTabs.SelectedTab.Text` with the correct result but `QCForm.chkLstLines.Items.Count` says 0 event though I have 10 Items checked

Form 2

```
public void frmResults_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)      
{
    int i = 0;
    this.Text = "Results - " + this.Title;

    switch (QCForm.tcTabs.SelectedTab.Text)
    {
        case "Line Checks":
            i = 0;                    
            while (i < QCForm.chkLstLines.Items.Count)
            {
                if ( QCForm.chkLstLines.GetItemChecked(i))
                {
                    lstFeatures.Items.Add(QCForm.chkLstLines.Items[i].ToString()); // VB6.GetItemString(QCForm.chkLstLines, i));
                }
                i++;
            }
    }
}
```

Edit

Form 1

```
    public static void ShowResults(string strRoutine, string strCaption)
    {
        var ResultsForm = new Form(this);

        //ResultsForm.Routine = strRoutine;
        //ResultsForm.Title = strCaption;

        strXMLFileName = xmlDocConfig.SelectSingleNode("config/routine[@key='" + strRoutine + "']/outputfname").Attributes.GetNamedItem("value").Value;

            strXMLFileName = clsUtilities.ReplacePathWildcards(strXMLFileName);

            strXMLFileName = clsUtilities.ReplacePathWildcards(frmNSTDBQC.xmlDocConfig.SelectSingleNode("config/routine[@key='G']/outputfname").Attributes.GetNamedItem("value").Value) + "\\" + strXMLFileName;

            //ResultsForm.DisplayFile = strXMLFileName;

            ResultsForm.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Form 2

```
    private frmNSTDBQC QCForm;

    public frmResults(frmNSTDBQC qcForm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        QCForm = qcForm;    
    }
```

Comment: Both checkboxes are public

Comment: Where are you initializing `QCForm`?

Comment: public partial class frmResults : Form
    {
        public frmNSTDBQC QCForm = new frmNSTDBQC();

Comment: Do not create new instance because it really has all items unchecked, use same one by passing through constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get same instance of `Form1` where you add checkboxes in this way

`Form2` is:

```
private Form1 form1;
public Form2(Form1 form)
{
    form1 = form;
}
// now you can use form1 as object
```

and now show `Form2` from `Form1`

```
var form2 = new Form(this); //pass instance
form2.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: @Deke I have added answer here, here `Form1` mean your first form having checkboxes and `Form2` is that form where you are accessing list.

Comment: Thanks X_TECH.  That is what I figured what was happening. I wanted to create a reference and not a new one but I coudnt quite get it.  I will try this code

Comment: @X_TECH dont have access to - this.. not sure why

Comment: @Deke Now, what the issue getting you?

Comment: Keyword 'this' is not a valid static property.  However when I remove the static  I get Windows form doesnt contain constructor that takes one arguement

Comment: @Deke Can you declare `ShowResults` as non static?

Comment: yes  but then I get -> I get Windows form doesnt contain constructor that takes one arguement

Comment: You need `var ResultsForm = new frmResults(this);` not `Form`

Comment: Thanks  Greatly appreciated  :)  Its the little things like that that give me problems

Answer (score 0):

If you have Both Forms open and you want them to interact, If you create first Form1 and then Form2, you can make Form2 able to see the changes in Form1 creating a CheckedListBox property inside Form2 and initializing it to the CheckedListBox object that stands inside Form1.
Pay attention that the reference is set after the CheckedListBox is created and its content initialized.

This however is a little bit a "raw" way to proceed. A better way to proceed would be to have a List of objects representing the data in the Form1

```
(E.g. List<Yourobject>)
```

as datasource of the CheckedListBox, bound to the properties in the listbox so that  a Checked property in the data is set/reset by your listbox, and then share just this list of data between the two forms using a

```
List<YourObject>
```

collection that you set in a property of Form2 When opening it after you initialize it in the Form1.

Remember that the class YourObject must implement a PropertyChanged on the Checked property to inform of changes and also that if that is the case, it is better to use a BindingList not just a List collection object because the BindingList implements the events to inform the UI that its content has changed such as the ObservableCollection does for WPF.
HTH